# Using WebRequest.ContentLength

Tags: c#, webrequest

```
string name = textBox.Text;
string favColour = textBox1.Text;

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

string postData = "name=" + name + "&favColour" + favColour;
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("mywebsite.com");

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream stream = request.Get;
```

Visual Studio 2015 has a problem with request.ContentLength.It says that there isn't a definition for ContentLength in WebRequest.

Comment: `WebRequest` do have a `ContentLength` property. See MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try casting to `HttpWebRequest`:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("mywebsite.com");
```

Also setting the `ContentLength` property manually is often not necessary as it will be done automatically when you write to the request stream.

Comment: Is it really needed. Cause `WebRequest` do have a `ContentLength` property